# Flutter - Retrieve value in getter outside of a .then() function

Tags: flutter, dart

I´ve created a `get` method outside the Widget tree to retrieve a value from a database provider. But the problem: Because it is a Future type I have to get this data with `.then()` ..and outside of `.then()` my `return` does not know this value.

Example:

```
String get _plannedHours {
    final calendarEntriesData =
        Provider.of<CalendarEntries>(context, listen: false);

    calendarEntriesData.getPlannedHoursFromMonth(_currentDate).then((value) {
      print(value.length); // I need this value
    });

    return "Value: 20"; // ....here!
  }
```

How I get this value outside of `.then()` to return a value to the Widget three?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` to access the value:

```
Future<String> get _plannedHours async {
    final calendarEntriesData =
        Provider.of<CalendarEntries>(context, listen: false);

   var value = await calendarEntriesData.getPlannedHoursFromMonth(_currentDate);
    return "Value: ${value.length}";
  }
```

Then you need to do:

```
await _plannedHours
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the Widget three if I want to call it I get: `The return type 'Future<Widget>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context`

Comment: you need to use a FutureBuilder widget

Comment: I badly can´t use a FutureBuilder Widget on this place :/ Are there other ways to achieve what I need?